# how to do a relation which has a has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `User` who can make an `Event`.  These are the organizers.

Other `User`s can go to these `Event`s as attendees.

How should I do the following relation?

User:

```
has_many :events, foreign_key: organizer_id
belongs_to :event
```

Event:

```
belongs_to :user #how to do the organizer and attendees distinction?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to create a `event_attends` table and put `user_id` and `event_id` columns there and `user_id` and `event_attend_id` in `events` table. Then you could create the associations like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_attends
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :event_attends
end

class EventAttend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Comment: Only one attendee per event? That sounds like a lonely, sad event.

Comment: May as well add a `has_many :attendees, through: :event_attends, source: :user` for good measure!

Answer (score 0):

You need two different relationships on each model with different names, but the same class. Also, you have a many-to-many relationship between attendees and events.

User

```
has_many :organized_events, class_name: "Event"
has_and_belongs_to_many :attended_events, class_name: "Event"
```

Event:

```
belongs_to :organizer, class_name: "User"
has_and_belongs_to_many :attendees, class_name: "User"
```